# Python Sorting a docx file

Tags: python, text-mining

I have a custom docx file dictionary where the words to be defined are on uppercase and bold. That is the only distinction from other words. The definitions are often large and with lines between, therefor it creates a new paragraph. As Sample:

A

ASDFG this means blah. 
  Blah comes from the aakak

It is still the same definition for ASDFG

MUG meaning of mug

ABBA musical group

I want to separate the paragraphs correctly to sort by the word to define (Upper case word) alphabetically. This is what I have

```
for p in document.paragraphs:
 if p.text.split(' ', 1)[0].isupper():
  #save as paragraph
  paragraph1 = text
 else:
  #concatenate to previews paragraph
  paragraph1 = text[-1] + text
```

Desired Output

A

ABBA definition

ASDFG definition

M

MUG definition

Thank you!

Comment: Reading this question makes little sense. Could you re-word it so that there's a bit more context? It's difficult to understand what you are asking when  you use examples which are completely withdrawn from the question.

Comment: After reading it for a fifth time, do you want to create a 'Literal Dictionary' not a 'Python Dict'? E.g. get the acronyms or words, get their definitions, then sort them alphabetically and add a letter to separate where the first letter rolls over?

Comment: With your code, what output do you get?

Comment: Hi Swift, yes, I wanted to do that. I found a way and I will paste the code here, Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 0):

```
#separate paragraphs by word to define
for p in document.paragraphs:
a = -1
if p.text.split(' ', 1)[0].isupper():
    texto.append(p.text)
    a = a + 1
else: 
    texto[a] = texto[a] + p.text

#sort the text
txt = sorted(texto)

# create an instance of a word document 
doc = docx.Document()

for t in txt:
doc_para = doc.add_paragraph(t)

docume = Document()

for t in txt:
   documen = docume.add_paragraph(t)

#export a docx named test with the sorted words
docume.save('test.docx')
```